# Android gesture recognition - circle's radius and center point

Tags: android, gesture, geometry

I am creating an android application. In which I have to find the gesture circle recognition and also find its center point and radius. I can recognize the circle using OnGesturePerformedListener. I can get only its right, top, left, bottom co-ordinates by using the following code.

```
RectF rectF = gesture.getBoundingBox();
rectF.left 
rectF.top 
rectF.right
rectF.bottom

public void onGesturePerformed(GestureOverlayView overlay, Gesture gesture) {
        ArrayList<Prediction> predictions = mLibrary.recognize(gesture);
        RectF rectF = gesture.getBoundingBox();
        if (predictions.size() > 0) {
            Prediction prediction = predictions.get(0);
            if (prediction.name.equals("Circle") && prediction.score > 1.0) {

            }
        }
    }
```

How can I find the center point and radius of the recognized circle?

Comment: isnt it a center of RectF ?

Comment: I recognized as circle. I can only get the RectF(Updated the question) value. But I want to find the center point and radius.

Comment: try the center of RectF then

Comment: did you mean rectF.centerX() and rectF.centerY() ? So can you tell me how to find radius of the circle?

Comment: RectF shorter edge length divided by two ?

Comment: is "RectF shorter edge length divided by two" to find the center of the circle?

Comment: imagine the square with the circle inside, you see it? so whats so hard in finding the center and radius?